# Regarding caffe caffe.paramspec has no parameter named compression

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I was trying to run a customized model on caffe.Unfortunately,I was only provided with a `trainval.prototxt` and `trainval.caffemodel`.

The exact error is as follows

> Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 54:17: Message type “caffe.ParamSpec has no field named compression
>   This is followed by
>   [upgrade_proto.cpp :79] check failed read protofromtextfile  failed to parse param file

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664703/error-parsing-text-format-caffe-netparameter-5417-message-type-caffe-convolu).

So should I assume that my version of caffe that I have on my system was different from the client's version of caffe and apparently the client version of caffe  has a slightly different proto definition??